# What is wrong with my SQL CASE syntax?

Tags: sql

I need help writing some SQL. I hate to ask such a rookie question, but what is wrong with the following SQL query?

```
select (case when mydate < '2010-1-1' Then '2000-1-1' ELSE mydate) from mytable;
```

The idea is that I want to get `mydate` from `mytable`, but if the date is before January, 1, 2010, I want the statement to return January 1, 2000 instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an `end`

```
case when mydate < '2010-1-1' Then '2000-1-1' ELSE mydate END
```

Comment: dasblinkenlight you beat me to it.

Comment: @ChristopherKelly Well, most questions with the word "syntax" in the title are like that :)

Answer (score 3):

you're missing the `end` at the end.

`select (case when mydate < '2010-1-1' Then '2000-1-1' ELSE mydate end) from mytable;`

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the END after mydate
select (case when mydate < '2010-1-1' Then '2000-1-1' ELSE mydate end) from mytable;